# Array of RDDs? One RDD for a time window

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question about bucketing time events with Spark, and the best way to handle it.

So I'm ingesting a very large dataset, with specific start/stop times for each event.

For instance, I might load in three weeks of data. Within the main time window, I divide that into buckets of smaller intervals. So 3 weeks divided into 24 hour time buckets, with an array that looks like [(start_epoch, stop_epoch), (start_epoch, stop_epoch), ...]

Within each time bucket I map/reduce my events down into a smaller set.

I'd like to keep the events split up by the time bucket they belong to.

What is the best way to handle this? Each map/reduce operation results in a new RDD so I'm effectively left with a large array of RDDs.

Is it "safe" to just loop over that array from the driver, and then do other transformations/actions on each RDD to get results each time window?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's just a very small array. It should be fine. Why not just try it?

Comment: Doing one hour bins for a 3 week period is ~504 give or take 1, so that is that many RDDs in an array. I just tried it, seemed to work OK, as long as I `.persist()` the main RDD that the smaller RDDs are derived from. So the main RDD isn't re-collected every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to think about it a bit differently: 
You want to read your data, and then "keyBy" time rounded to hour resolution. And then you can reduceByKey(or combineByKey if you want another type in output).

While working with spark it's not necessary to collect items into arrays by some key(even antipattern)

RDD[Event] -> keyBy ts rounded to hour -> RDD[(hour, event)] -> reduceByKey(i.e. hour) -> RDD[(hour, aggregated view of all events in this hour)]

Comment: This helped! Yes I was able to set the Key to the nearest hour (time - (time %3600)) and then go from there!